# I am looking for some basic mechanical parts to build structures(prototypes)?

Tags: metals, robotics, building-design, prototyping

I am looking for something like this to make my robot ideas as prototype. But I don't know it's name! Also if there are better options I will happy to know.

[image]
<sub>(source: [instructables.com](https://cdn.instructables.com/FQC/7ENO/IW5JB2UM/FQC7ENOIW5JB2UM.MEDIUM.jpg))</sub>

[image]

Comment: For early stage prototypes, Lego Technic is a viable choice.

Comment: Or fischer technic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is described as "Perforated", So a quick google for "Perforated Square Tubing Steel" produced: https://www.discountsteel.com/items/Galvanized_Steel_Perforated_Square_Tube.cfm

"80-20" is a brand name, and the product that @Donald Gibson was referring to can more generally be found called "T Slot Extrusion"

Comment: That would be "T" slot, not "v" slot.

Comment: Edited accordingly - V slot is a slightly different form designed to work as a linear rail as well as a structural member, so T is the more general term

Answer (score 1):

Try 80-20 structural tubing. It is available is various sectional sizes, often used for robotics and machine framing.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to 80/20 you could use "unistrut" or "channel strut" framing which may be more readily available at a big box store.

[image: unistrut]